# Why am I getting error "Unable to allocate the required address spaces ..."?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

When I do a deploy to our staging environment I'm getting error " Unable to allocate the required address spaces for the deployment in a new or predefined subnet that is contained within the specified virtual network."

Our virtual network has a address space of 10.0.0.0/26.  That should give me 59 addresses and I only have 3 active roles.  Is there a way to check available network addresses or somehow refresh?  I've seen another question on this back in preview and the solution was to delete the existing virtual network... which is not an option for us.  We have our production environment on this virtual network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was because there was a new role defined.  For every role I need to include a InstanceAddress with a Subnet defined.